# An analytic function on the unit disk is Lipschitz on proper subdisks

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following exercise in preparation for an exam and I would appreciate it if I could get a hint (not a solution please).

Let $f$ be an analytic function on the unit disk $D$ and assume that $f$ is bounded on $D$, namely $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z\in D$. Fix $0<r<1$. Find a constant $C$ depending on $M$ and $r$ such that for all points $z,w$ of modulus less than $r$, we have $$|f(z)-f(w)|\leq C|z-w|$$

Comment: Cauchy formula for derivaties, and Cauchy estimates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it.

Assume in what follows that $z_0=0$ (otherwise just a little more care is needed).

By Cauchy's estimate for derivatives we have that for any, $$|f'(z_0)|\leq \frac{M}{r}, \qquad \forall 0<r<1$$

Since $f'(z_0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(_0)}{z-z_0}$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $-\epsilon\leq\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)\leq\epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0|<\delta$ so in particular $$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right|\leq |\epsilon+f'(z_0)|$$

Finally just let $\epsilon_r$ by the supremum of all $\epsilon>0$ such that the corresponding $\delta<r$ and we get $$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right|\leq \epsilon_r+|f'(z_0)|\leq \epsilon_r+\frac{M}{r}$$ so our sought for constant is simply $$C=\epsilon_r+\frac{M}{r}$$

If $z_0$ is not the origin, then Cauchy's estimate only applies for $0<t<dist(z_0,\partial D)$, which depends on $r$ and the same argument applies.